Unity XRGrabInteractable weird position behavior
my code spawns 10 objects of class node, each if which move around during the lifetime of the scene. each node has a XRGrabInteractable object that allows them to be moved using a controller in VR. this only works for the first few seconds then they the node (sphere) and the XRGrabInteractable positions get out of sync. why does this happen and how can i fix it and i can't grab the sphere anymore, but the grabbable objects is still there if i search for it and when i grab it it i grab the sphere; meaning the sphere and the grab object are at different positions
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.Interaction.Toolkit;

public class Connection
{
    public Node a;
    public Node b;
    public LineRenderer line;

    public Connection(Node a, Node b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        GameObject lineObject = new GameObject();
        line = lineObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        line.startWidth = 0.1f;
        line.endWidth = 0.1f;
        line.SetPosition(0, a.position);
        line.SetPosition(1, b.position);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        line.SetPosition(0, a.position);
        line.SetPosition(1, b.position);
    }
}

public class Node
{
    public Vector3 position;
    public Vector3 color = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    public bool grabbed = false;


    private XRGrabInteractable grabInteractable;


    public GameObject sphere;
    public float q = 0.09f;  // charge of the node
    public float k = 6.67f;  // coulomb's constant

    public float spring_constant = 0.5f;

    public List<Connection> connections = new List<Connection>();

    public Node(Vector3 pos, Connection[] connections = null)
    {
        position = pos;
        color = new Vector3(Random.Range(0, 1), Random.Range(0, 1), Random.Range(0, 1));
        // draw sphere
        GameObject sphereObject = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        sphereObject.transform.position = position;
        // set sphere scale and color
        sphereObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        sphereObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(color.x, color.y, color.z);
        // add interactable component
        grabInteractable = sphereObject.AddComponent<XRGrabInteractable>();
        grabInteractable.onSelectEntered.AddListener(OnGrab);
        grabInteractable.onSelectExited.AddListener(OnRelease);


        this.sphere = sphereObject;
        if (connections != null)
        {
            foreach (Connection connection in connections)
            {
                this.connections.Add(connection);
            }
        }


    }

    public void apply_repulsion(Node other)
    {
        Vector3 direction = other.position - position;
        float distance = direction.magnitude;
        float force = k * q * q / (distance * distance);
        Vector3 repulsion = direction.normalized * force;
        position -= repulsion;
    }

    public void apply_attraction(Node other)
    {
        Vector3 direction = other.position - position;
        float distance = direction.magnitude;
        float force = spring_constant * distance;
        Vector3 attraction = direction.normalized * force;
        position += attraction;
    }

    void OnGrab(XRBaseInteractor interactor)
    {
        // Implement logic when the node is grabbed
        // For example, you might want to disable physics interactions while grabbed
        grabbed = true;
        // set sphere to interactor position
        this.position = interactor.transform.position;
        this.grabInteractable.transform.position = interactor.transform.position;

    }


    void OnRelease(XRBaseInteractor interactor)
    {
        // Implement logic when the node is released
        // For example, you might want to re-enable physics interactions when released
        grabbed = false;

    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (position.y < 1)
        {
            position.y = 1;
        }
        sphere.transform.position = position;

        foreach (Connection connection in connections)
        {
            connection.Update();
        }

        // change position of grabinteractable
        grabInteractable.transform.position = position;

        


    }
}


public class spawn_graph : MonoBehaviour
{
    Node[] nodes;
    void Start()
    {
        // 10 random spheres each with 3 random connections
        nodes = new Node[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            nodes[i] = new Node(new Vector3(Random.Range(-5, 5), Random.Range(0, 10), Random.Range(-5, 5)));


        }

        // add 3 random connections to each node
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Connection[] connections = new Connection[3];
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                Node b = nodes[Random.Range(0, 10)];
                while (b == nodes[i])
                {
                    b = nodes[Random.Range(0, 10)];
                }

                connections[j] = new Connection(nodes[i], b);

            }
            nodes[i].connections.AddRange(connections);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // apply repulsion
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nodes.Length; j++)
            {
                if (i != j && nodes[i] != null && nodes[j] != null && nodes[i].grabbed == false && nodes[j].grabbed == false)
                {
                    nodes[i].apply_repulsion(nodes[j]);
                }
            }
        }

        // update positions
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Length; i++)
        {
            nodes[i].Update();

        }
    }
}

